# Find duplicate values between two separate javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two javascript arrays of objects:

```
var fullDateRange=[{date:"4/1/18",value:0},{date:"4/2/18",value:0},{date:"4/3/18",value:0},{date:"4/4/18",value:0},{date:"4/5/18",value:0}]
```

and

```
var actualDateRange=[{date:"4/1/18",value:1},{date:"4/3/18",value:3},{date:"4/5/18",value:5}]
```

I'm trying to loop through the fullDateRange array, see if any of the actualDateRange dates exist, and increment the value. But I keep getting duplicates with this code:

```
   function outputDeltaDates(fullDateObj, responseObj) {
    var dateArr = [],
      valueArr = [];
    $.each(fullDateObj, function(index) {
      var fullDate = this;
      var counter = 0
      $.each(responseObj, function(index) {
        var fullResponse = this;
        if (fullResponse['date'] == fullDate['date']) {
          valueArr.push(fullResponse['value'])
          dateArr.push(fullDate['date'])
        } else {
          if (!dateArr.includes(fullDate['date'])) {
            valueArr.push(0)
            dateArr.push(fullDate['date'])
          }
        }
      })
    })
    return [valueArr, dateArr]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increment the objects value property if the date exists in the other array, simply loop it once and increment value if the date is found in `actualDateRange`

```js
var fullDateRange=[{date:"4/1/18",value:0},{date:"4/2/18",value:0},{date:"4/3/18",value:0},{date:"4/4/18",value:0},{date:"4/5/18",value:0}]
var actualDateRange=[{date:"4/1/18",value:1},{date:"4/3/18",value:3},{date:"4/5/18",value:5}]

fullDateRange.forEach(e => {
    let act = actualDateRange.find(a => a.date === e.date);
    if (act) e.value += act.value;
})

console.log(fullDateRange);
```

Comment: Wait, a.value doesn't exist in the forEach loop. How do I access the "found" date row in 2nd list? @baao

Comment: Edited the answer to do that @Ethans123, I wasn't sure what you want to add

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, push incremented counter to **valueArr** i.e

```
valueArr.push(++counter)
```

instead of 
**fullResponse['value']** (which will push actualDateRange value)

```js
var fullDateRange=[{date:"4/1/18",value:0},{date:"4/2/18",value:0},{date:"4/3/18",value:0},{date:"4/4/18",value:0},{date:"4/5/18",value:0}]
var actualDateRange=[{date:"4/1/18",value:1},{date:"4/3/18",value:3},{date:"4/5/18",value:5}]

function outputDeltaDates(fullDateObj, responseObj) {
    var dateArr = [],
      valueArr = [];
    $.each(fullDateObj, function(index) {
      var fullDate = this;
      var counter = 0
      $.each(responseObj, function(index) {
        var fullResponse = this;
        if (fullResponse['date'] == fullDate['date']) {
          valueArr.push(++counter)
          dateArr.push(fullDate['date'])
        } else {
          if (!dateArr.includes(fullDate['date'])) {
            valueArr.push(0)
            dateArr.push(fullDate['date'])
          }
        }
      })
    })
     return [valueArr, dateArr]
  } 

console.log(outputDeltaDates(fullDateRange, actualDateRange))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rvVqdW?editors=1010